# I received a notice of suspension letter for alleged misconduct that is unfounded

Tags: work-environment

I received a notice of suspension letter for alleged misconduct and I responded to my allegations.It is now a month and the employer has not said anything to me. What should i do? My union say i must wait but im frustrated to come to work and do nothing.

Comment: Best course of action is to talk to your union again.  Help yourself set expectations with respect to time frames and possible outcomes.  The union will likely have a ballpark idea as to how long these things take and what the possible outcomes are.  The documentary "Waiting for Superman" has a piece about teachers in New York who get put on indefinite suspension for unfounded allegations.  They spend the rest of their career wiling away the time in an office doing nothing.

Comment: Related - [How to respond to false accusations](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/36344/whats-the-most-professional-and-constructive-response-to-false-accusations)

Comment: Why are you coming to work if you're suspended?  "Suspended" to me means you shouldn't be in the workplace.  Coming in but doing nothing seems ridiculous.

Comment: Since you are in a union the best course of action is to either let the union handle it for you or get a lawyer to represent you.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Myles - If you are feeling frustrated, follow up with your union and get your frustration out of your system, at least for a while. Repeat in writing that you contest the allegation of misconduct, that you are willing to cooperate with any investigation and that it is important to you that the allegation of misconduct be cleared up/resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a member of the union, so please excuse me if my response is off-base. But, don't unions have representatives and/or delegates available to members who need them? It sounds very much like you need representation. Normally I would suggest you obtain a labor lawyer, but as a union member try to get someone assigned to your case by the union.

Once you have representation, tell your entire story to them. Have them approach your employer and request complete documentation on your alleged offense.

It is likely that once they see the evidence, they will be able to poke holes in the story. If they succeed in completely disassembling the allegations as false, they can then officially request a retraction be placed in your HR file.

Comment: Yes, representation of the members is exactly what union membership is supposed to cover.